# Jest: How to test that a component has a certain ref attribute?

Tags: jestjs, use-ref

JSX

```
const MyComp = ({ myDOMElRef }) => <div id="x" ref={ myDOMElRef } />
```

test

```
const mockedElRef = 'whatever';
// ... set up stuff
instance=shallow(<MyComp ref={ mockedElRef } />
expect(instance).toHaveProp('ref', mockedElRef);
```

Ref is a special prop so the test fails. **How to check the div with id x has ref as passed into MyComp?**

Answer (score 1):

**React 16+**

```
const domElement = instance.get(0);
expect(domElement.ref).toBe(mockedElRef);
```

Note: Up until React 15 it was possible to use `instance()` instead of `get(0)` on the wrapper returned from `shallow()`.